# Is there a default GID for wheel group on Debian Linices?

Tags: debian, security, sudo, group

I know Debian doesn't use the wheel group by default, but I'm to the bottom of my todo list for securing some old operating systems that I don't want to rebuild from scratch and running the CIS benchmarks against it.  I want to go through the exercise of [adding a wheel group](https://wiki.debian.org/WHEEL/PAM), even though I might ask for a waiver for it later on, what I'd like to know is, is there a default gid for wheel or do I just pick one that's nominally unused under 100?

Comment: I’m curious why you want to *add* a wheel group — the best way to secure a wheel group is to not have one in the first place...

Comment: @StephenKitt https://github.com/dev-sec/cis-dil-benchmark/blob/master/controls/5_4_user_accounts_and_environments.rb  (see 5.6) I'm just rather brainlessly trying to make a round peg go in a square hole

Comment: This illustrates one of the problems I have with the CIS Benchmark. They have a one-size-fits-all solution for each problem. Alternate, and maybe better, solutions will get you scored down.

Comment: @don yep, but we're more than welcome to submit PR's at least.  I've got one out there.  I didn't find out there was an ubuntu version of the CIS benchmark (still don't know where it is, someone at my company just told me it exists) until I made it to nearly my last remediation.  Oh well, it's a fun ride.

Comment: OK, thanks. On Debian I would just install `pam_wheel` without a `wheel` group, or even `chmod 700 /bin/su` (with a statoverride to avoid having the permissions restored on upgrades).

Answer (score 1):

I believe systems which has group wheel defined as a default doesnt agree on which numerical id it should be.
So if you take any arbitrary numerical id doesn't really matter.

The hell comes when importing tar files and cpio archives from systems with another definition of wheel (and other groups.)

Comment: Yes, and avoiding the pains of hell is what I pray for every night.  If my systems are relatively identical I'd be better off choosing an id and applying it to all the systems than leaving it to chance with groupadd though, right?

Comment: yes, taking groupadd's decisions out of the picture is good.

Comment: i believe the policies in debian for example is primarily around checking which interval a later on added group ends in.